# Postman can not send request to local http server

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, curl, server

Here is a http-server written in `Node.js`

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

var jsonFile = require('./data.json')

    const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.write(JSON.stringify(jsonFile))
    });

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

As you see , I return a json data from `data.json` file. When I open link http://127.0.0.1:3000/ on `Chrome`, I get json reponse. However when I do on `postman`, it always keeps sending request but **no response**. Is there anything wrong?

## EDIT(Remove postman tag)

I also test `curl ttp://127.0.0.1:3000/` and no response either.So I think it may not be caused by `postman`.

## EDIT(curl get response)

There is a strange thing that curl return response after **a long time**. And `curl` get error

> curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Comment: Check if postman has a proxy mis/configured.

Comment: I have never set proxy.

Comment: Does it work if you try to use it `http://[::1]:3000` instead of 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'?

Comment: I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to ::1 port 3000: Connection refused`

Comment: Do you have the SSL Certificate Verification enabled in Settings>General? If true, try to disable this.

Comment: add `res.end()` after `res.write(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `res.end()` after write. Or use `res.send()` instead of write()

Comment: As I understood it, it was not only Postman, but also `curl`. My guess is that Chrome, as well as other browsers, are made to handle more imperfect data, maybe that's why it works in the browser. At least browsers seem to handle broken HTML very well... sorry if my answer doesn't fit the question.